Extracting Data From a Web Page with Selection Options
I have a webpage (https://deos.udel.edu/data/daily_retrieval.php) I want to extract data from. However, the data is precipitation data related to a specific selection made within the webpage. The specific selections include Station, and date. I am using the R package rvest and I am not sure if this data request can be done in R with rvest. Some of the source code of interest for the webpage may be found below.
        <label class="retsection" for="station">Station:</label><br>
        <select class="statlist" name="station" id="station" size="10">
<option class="select_input" value="DTBR" selected>Adamsville, DE-Taber</option>
<option class="select_input" value="DBUR">Angola, DE-Burton Pond</option>
<option class="select_input" value="DWHW">Atglen, PA-Wolfs Hollow</option>
<option class="select_input" value="DBBB">Bethany Beach, DE-Boardwalk</option>
<option class="select_input" value="DBNG">Bethany Beach, DE-NGTS</option>
<option class="select_input" value="DBKB">Blackbird, DE-NERR</option>
<option class="select_input" value="DBRG">Bridgeville, DE</option>

        <label class="retsection">Date:<br> </label>
        <select name='month' size='6' length='10'>
<option value='1'>January</option>
<option value='2'>February</option>
<option value='3'>March</option>
<option value='4'>April</option>
<option value='5'>May</option>
<option value='6'>June</option>
<option value='7'>July</option>
<option value='8' selected>August</option>
<option value='9'>September</option>
<option value='10'>October</option>
<option value='11'>November</option>
<option value='12'>December</option>
</select>
<select name='day' size='6' length='4'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2' selected>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
<option value='6'>6</option>


My initial thought is this task cannot be done since the precipitation data is not actively displayed on the webpage... the data pops up in a separate window after the selection is made. I have an access key provided by the webpage but am not 100% sure if it can be used to retrieve the large dataset I am wishing to pull.

Is this type of data request feasible with rvest?
What would be some suggested methods to extract large amounts of data via R. For example a years worth of precipitation data for a specific station of interest.

Thanks.

What data precisely do you want?

I am interested in daily precipitation values for the Smyrna, DE-DASEF station across multiple years (2020, 2021, 2022, 2023). This way I can join the rain events that occurred the day prior to a water quality sample taken from that same geographic area. Rainfall preceding a sampling event directly effects certain parameters. I want to automate this analysis process so I can replicate between stations and not spend many hours data mining individual rain events.

Disclaimer:
You probably don't need to use this. DEOS have ways of downloading historical data as CSVs. Beyond that, make sure if you're scraping the site, you leave some time between each request, otherwise you'll be annoying the owners, and they're likely to block you, or slow your responses down.
Answer:
The trick with this is that the parameters are included in the URL. So we only need to adjust those, in order to get a new result, as below:
pacman::p_load(glue, rvest) # glue makes adding parameters to a string easier/cleaner

url <- "https://deos.udel.edu/odd-divas/station_daily.php?network={network}&station={station}&month={m}&day={d}&year={y}"

network <- "DEOS"
station <- "DTBR"
m <- 8
d <- 3
y <- 2024

url <- glue(url)
glue(url) |>
  read_html() |>
  html_table()

Output:
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  X1         X2            X3        X4       
  <chr>      <chr>         <chr>     <chr>    
1 ID         DTBR          Network   DEOS     
2 City/State Adamsville/DE Elevation 51 ft.   
3 Latitude   38° 52' N     Longitude 75° 42' W

[[2]]
# A tibble: 24 × 20
    Hour Temp                  \…¹ Temp                …² Dew Point           …³
   <int>                     <dbl>                  <dbl>                  <dbl>
 1     0                      77.2                   25.1                   73.7
 2     1                      76.7                   24.8                   74  
 3     2                      77.1                   25                     72.2
 4     3                      76.8                   24.9                   71.5
 5     4                      76                     24.5                   72.3
 6     5                      75.3                   24.1                   71.9
 7     6                      74.8                   23.8                   72.2
 8     7                      76.3                   24.6                   73.4
 9     8                      79.2                   26.2                   74.4
10     9                      82.6                   28.1                   74.6
# ℹ 14 more rows
# ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​`Temp                  \n(°F)`,
#   ²​`Temp                  \n(°C)`, ³​`Dew Point                  \n(°F)`
# ℹ 16 more variables: `Dew Point                  \n(°C)` <dbl>,
#   `Rel Hum.                  \n(%)` <int>,
#   `Wind Spd.                  \n(MPH)` <dbl>,
#   `Wind Spd.                  \n(m/s)` <dbl>, …
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 × 11
  High Temp.                  \n…¹ Low Temp.           …² Avg. Temp.          …³
                             <dbl>                  <dbl>                  <dbl>
1                             88.7                   71.1                   80.1
# ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​`High Temp.                  \n(°F)`,
#   ²​`Low Temp.                  \n(°F)`, ³​`Avg. Temp.                  \n(°F)`
# ℹ 8 more variables: `Avg. Dew Point                  \n(°F)` <dbl>,
#   `Avg. Rel Hum                  \n(%)` <int>,
#   `Avg. Wind Spd                  \n(MPH)` <dbl>,
#   `Avg. Wind Dir                  \n(°)` <chr>,
#   `Peak Gust                  \n(MPH)` <dbl>, …

[[4]]
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  X1                                                                            
  <chr>                                                                         
1 Note: All observations were obtained from the Delaware Environmental Observin…

[[5]]
# A tibble: 3 × 1
  X1                                                                          
  <chr>                                                                       
1 "Copyright © 2004-2024 DEOS"                                                
2 "Please read the                   Data Disclaimer\n before using any data."
3 "Questions or comments about this page? Click                   here\n."    

To extend this to multiple days, you could use a for loop, or map(), or any number of other functions which do roughly the same thing. But without knowing for sure the information you are wanting from that site, I would say it's highly likely you can get it from them in other ways.

I stumbled upon the historical csv download function DEOS has built. That built-in function allows you to export data for a single day or a sum of total precipitation data for a month but it does allow you to export multiple days worth of precipitation data over a year. I am interested in daily precipitation values for the Smyrna, DE-DASEF station across multiple years (2020, 2021, 2022, 2023). This way I can join the rain events that occurred the day prior to a water quality sample taken from that same geographic area. Rainfall preceding a sampling event directly effects certain parameters.

I'm guessing you meant 'but it does not allow you to export multiple days worth of precipitation data over a year'?

Correct. I meant to say it does not allow the user to export multiple days worth of precipitation data over a year. Sorry for the typo.

okay so upon further inspection, it looks like they don't actually provide a data export for daily data unfortunately. There is the option of using their JSON backend (e.g. https://ares.deos.udel.edu/almanac/almanac.php?start=2024-08-01+00:00&end=2024-08-01+23:59&data_type=Precipitation&method=total&mode=basic ) but it still just has the option of a single day or aggregated results

The problem is that they're doing the queries on the server side, which means we can't actually access all the data on our end

Thanks for this comment. I have already entered into discussion with the website owner/host about my data needs. Hopefully they can either provide the larger datasets to me or we can work towards a resolution where users can pull data directly into R or SAS.
